# Multidimensional array using objects

Tags: php, arrays, object

Is it possible to stop the loop from overwriting the previous value?

```php
<?php
foreach (array('email1', 'email2') as $line) {
  $x = [
    $line => [
      "Reports" => [
        (object) [
          "ReportType" => "1",
          "SummaryFrequency" => [
            (object) [
              "FrequencyType" => "8011",
              "SecondsPast" => "32400",
            ],
          ],
          "Filter" => (object) [
            "ClauseType" => "or",
            "RuleField" => "",
            "RuleOperator" => "",
            "RuleValue" => "",
            "ClauseChildren" => [
              (object) [
                "ClauseType" => "",
                "RuleField" => "BackupJobDetail.TimeSinceStarted",
                "RuleOperator" => "int_lte",
                "RuleValue" => "86400",
              ],
            ],
          ],
        ],
      ],
    ],
  ];
}

print_r($x);
```

https://phpize.online/?phpses=e658de0de3dc1ed5a4d8d27ecebf567a&sqlses=null&php_version=php8&sql_version=mysql57

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment you overwrite `$x` each time, if you want to make it an array with `$line` as each index, create an empty array and then add the new items in with new index...

```
$x = [];
foreach (array('email1', 'email2') as $line) {
  $x[$line] = [
      "Reports" => [
          (object) [
```

Comment: nice, thats working great. only thing now, is im sending like this `$account_get_user_profile->OverrideEmailSettings = $x;`  which puts the OverrideEmailSettings as `[OverrideEmailSettings] => Array` but i need that to be `[OverrideEmailSettings] => stdClass Object`

Comment: I've not sure where `OverrideEmailSettings` comes from, but could it be that you need to use `$x[$line] = (object)[`

Comment: i have already done that for another reason, but that only makes `[email1] => stdClass Object` - `OverrideEmailSettings` is before this array, and where i am sending this array too - `$account_get_user_profile->OverrideEmailSettings = $x;`

Comment: OK, so have you tried adding (object) before the `$x` - `$account_get_user_profile->OverrideEmailSettings = (object)$x;`

Comment: that does seem to have changed it but im getting an error.
I know it's probably an API error, but its returning this - is there a generic way to find out what line is causing the error based on offset 205? `400 Invalid request (parse error: expected number near offset 205 of '1')`

Comment: It's difficult to know what the error is and where it comes from.  If you are creating some JSON so send to the api, then find out what the JSON is and it may be fixable.  This seems to be another problem though and not sure if it is part of this question.

Comment: got it, some of the values were integers :)